# Cannot find dependencies while creating dll

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, dll

I try to create a dll from all of my classes with VS command prompt but all classes using externall dll's won't do.

The program uses some dlls from OpenGl that I stored in the bin folder and it works fine while running the program

But I get error CS0246, namespace could not be found, missing directive when I try to create a dll from all those classes.

The line I use is:

```
csc /target:library /out:Engine.DLL *
```

All System namespace are found but all external dlls are not.

Do I need to add a path to the external dlls in VS environment?

Comment: Have you tried using /reference:YourExternalAssembly1.dll;YourExternalAssembly2.dll before "*"?  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yabyz3h4.aspx)

Comment: That seems to be getting somewhere, it is missing the meta files so I get them and see. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly need to use the `/reference` (or `/r`) compiler option for your external assemblies ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yabyz3h4.aspx) is the official documentation from msdn):

```
csc /target:library /r:Assembly1.dll;Assembly2.dll out/Engine.DLL *
```

[/lib](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/s5bac5fx.aspx) could also be useful if your external assemblies are located in different folders and if you don't want to use `/r` with a full path (like `/r:../test/folder/subfolder/Assembly1.dll`)

Comment: Ok, it seems to be the solution but now the problem are missing files on my side. I guess once I managed to gather it all it will go fine. Thanks.